# Overwrite the properties file if command line value is present

Tags: java, properties, command-line-arguments

I have a program which will read everything from `config.properties` file if command line does not contain any arguments apart from config.properties file location. Below is my config.properties file-

```
NUMBER_OF_THREADS: 100
NUMBER_OF_TASKS: 10000
ID_START_RANGE: 1
TABLES: TABLE1,TABLE2
```

If I am running my program from the command prompt like this-

`java -jar Test.jar "C:\\test\\config.properties"`

It should read all the four properties from the `config.properties` file. But suppose if I am running my program like this-

`java -jar Test.jar "C:\\test\\config.properties" 10 100 2 TABLE1 TABLE2 TABLE3`

then it should read all the properties from the arguments and overwrite the properties in config.properties file.

Below is my code which is working fine in this scenario-

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {

            readPropertyFiles(args);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOG.error("Threw a Exception in" + CNAME + e);
        }
    }

    private static void readPropertyFiles(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {

        location = args[0];

        prop.load(new FileInputStream(location));

        if(args.length >= 1) {
            noOfThreads = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
            noOfTasks = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);
            startRange = Integer.parseInt(args[3]);

            tableName = new String[args.length - 4];
            for (int i = 0; i < tableName.length; i++) {
                tableName[i] = args[i + 4];
                tableNames.add(tableName[i]);
            }
        } else {
            noOfThreads = Integer.parseInt(prop.getProperty("NUMBER_OF_THREADS").trim());
            noOfTasks = Integer.parseInt(prop.getProperty("NUMBER_OF_TASKS").trim());
            startRange = Integer.parseInt(prop.getProperty("ID_START_RANGE").trim());
            tableNames = Arrays.asList(prop.getProperty("TABLES").trim().split(","));
        }

        for (String arg : tableNames) {

            //Some Other Code

        }
    }
```

**Problem Statement:-**

Now what I am trying to do is- Suppose if any person is running program like this

`java -jar Test.jar "C:\\test\\config.properties" 10`

then in my program, it should overwrite `noOfThreads` only-

```
noOfThreads should be 10 instead of 100
```

And suppose if that person is running program like this-

`java -jar Test.jar "C:\\test\\config.properties" 10 100`

then in my program, it should overwrite `noOfThreads` and `noOfTasks` only-

```
noOfThreads should be 10 instead of 100
noOfTasks should be 100 instead of 10000
```

And possible other use cases as well.

Can anyone suggest me how to achieve this scenario? Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a loop, instead.

```
List<String> paramNames = new ArrayList<String>{"NUMBER_OF_THREADS", "NUMBER_OF_TASKS", 
            "ID_START_RANGE", "TABLES"}; // Try to reuse the names from the property file
Map<String, String> paramMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
...
// Validate the length of args here
...
// As you table names can be passed separately. You need to handle that somehow. 
// This implementation would work when number of args will be equal to number of param names
for(int i = 0; i< args.length; i++) {
   paramMap.put(paramNames[i], args[i]); 
}

props.putAll(paramMap);
... // Here props should have it's values overridden with the ones provided
```

Comment: ASK Adeel. Thanks Adeel for the help. I am not using JDK1.7 so cannot use those braces. :( And also can you provide me the full flow where I am supposed to put this to make this thing work. Thanks for the help.

Comment: TechGeeky: I have replaced the diamond operators, so you can use it with Java 6.

Answer (score 8):

When defining command line input as follows

`java -jar Test.jar "C:\\test\\config.properties" 10 100`

It means one must always provide `noOfThreads` to override `noOfTasks`.

To solve this you could specify these as system properties on command line along with file location which other wise has a default location too. For example: -

`java -jar -Dconfig.file.location="C:\\test\\config.properties" -DNUMBER_OF_THREADS=10 Test.jar`

Then.

1. Read file properties into `Properties`.
2. Iterate over keys in the properties and find corresponding `System.getProperty()`.
3. If value is found override corresponding entry in the properties.

This way no matter how many new properties you introduce your code will always remain same.

You can go step further and encapsulate all of this in a `PropertyUtil` that also provide utility methods like `getIntProperty()`, `getStringProperty()` etc.

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Properties;

public class PropertyUtil {

  private static final String DEFAULT_CONFIG_FILE_LOCATION = "config.properties";

  private String configFileLocation;

  private Properties properties;

  public PropertyUtil() throws IOException {

    this(DEFAULT_CONFIG_FILE_LOCATION);
  }

  public PropertyUtil(String configFileLocation) throws IOException {

    this.configFileLocation = configFileLocation;
    this.properties = new Properties();
    init();
  }

  private void init() throws IOException {

    properties.load(new FileInputStream(this.configFileLocation));

    for (Object key : this.properties.keySet()) {

      String override = System.getProperty((String) key);

      if (override != null) {

        properties.put(key, override);
      }
    }
  }

  public int getIntProperty(String key) {

    return this.properties.contains(key) ? Integer.parseInt(properties.get(key)) : null;
  }

  public String getStringProperty(String key) {

    return (String) this.properties.get(key);
  }
}
```

Examples.

config.properties

```
NUMBER_OF_THREADS=100
NUMBER_OF_TASKS=10000
ID_START_RANGE=1
TABLES=TABLE1,TABLE2
```

To override `NUMBER_OF_THREADS`.

`java -jar -Dconfig.file.location="C:\\test\\config.properties" -DNUMBER_OF_THREADS=10 Test.jar`

Short hand example to read 'NUMBER_OF_THREADS' as int.

```
new PropertyUtil(System.getProperty("config.file.location")).getIntProperty("NUMBER_OF_THREADS");
```

Comment: Thanks sgp15 for the suggestion. If you can provide me an example basis on my scenario then I would be able to understand much better. Thanks for the help.

Comment: +1 for -D option alone. Btw, your getIntProperty() seems broken. So, I fixed it. You are welcome to revert it, if you think it was actually correct.

Answer (score 0):

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.load(new FileInputStream("C:\\test\\config.properties"));
```

Then as per your command line arguments set the individual properties as :

```
setProperty("NUMBER_OF_THREADS", args[1]);
setProperty("NUMBER_OF_TASKS", args[2]);
```

This won't overwrite the existing config.properties file.